# Does $f'$ non-negative except at finitely many points imply that $f$ is weakly increasing?

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x)$ be strictly increasing over $[a,b]$ and twice-differentiable over $(a,b)$. Suppose that for some twice-differentiable function $f(x)$,
$$ g'(x) f'(x) \geq 0 \:\:\: \forall x \in (a,b) $$

Since $g$ is strictly increasing, $g'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ and $g'(x)>0$ except possibly at finitely many points. This implies that $f'(x) \geq 0$ except at finitely many points. Can we conclude from this that $f(x)$ is weakly increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Since $f$ is twice differentiable, $f'$ is continuous. Continuity implies that $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. If this were not the case, then there exists an interval $I$ such that $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in I$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(x)$ is continuous, we have that if $f'(u) < 0 \implies f'(v) < 0, \forall v \in (u-\epsilon,u+\epsilon)$ by continuity of $f'(x)$ at $u$ which contradicts the fact that $f'(x)<0$ at finitely many points. This implies $f'(x) \geq 0, \forall x \in (a,b)$

Regarding $g'(x) > 0$ except at finitely many points, you are correct i.e., $g(x) = x^3$ is a strictly increasing function and $g'(0) = 0$.